# How to modify possible values screen timeout on rooted devices?

Tags: settings, screen

I've managed to root my device.
I wanted to keep my screen awake forever. However when I looked around the Settings, the maximum value is 1 hour in the Display settings. There's a 'never' in Developer settings, but only when device is being charged. I used Tasker to set the timeout to Never, but it gets changed back when I click the  Display Settings. I used Android wakelocks but they stop working when they're removed from the memory.

I know those settings are practical enough, but as a geek I would like to know how to get 'Never' appear in my Display Settings.

EDIT: To repeat again, I **DO NOT** want to use an app or a wakelock to accomplish this. I just would like to have my ROM (/system partition) modifed so that 'Screen timeout: Never' appears in my Settings.

Comment: TheDarken's Wake Lock ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl)) had always worked fine for me for the purpose. Never had it removed from memory either.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks for the reply, but I've expressed in my question that I simply want a 'never' in the settings.  For keeping deviceawake, Tasker is perfect enough because it can detect when I changed display settings.

Comment: I'm currently researching this exact question, with pretty much the same parameters as you (my sympathies for the frustrating responses).  One app I've found to be quite promising: [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22).  This app -- after using ADB to grant additional permissions -- allows you to directly access and modify the settings' values saved in their respective .db containers, many of which are not accessible through the frontend UI.  Of course, the trick is finding the correct one and not bricking your device in the process...

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep screen awake forever:

1. Download [No Screen Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.k2.no.screen.off) app and install it.
2. (**Ignore this PLEASE**) If you know android programming, you can use this snippet in your app:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

3. Some phones have **"Keep screen turned on" option** in Screen timeout
   settings.
4. (**Requires Root**) You can use **[PerApp](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1658251) for** making **change** in Screen timeout
   settings **and add your own value**.(customize)
5. There is a **stay awake option in "Developer Options"** to Stay awake
   **while USB debugging and charging**.

Comment: Apart from the second, I have ALL methods mentioned in my question body... I just would like to *be able to* use the third method. (The 4th method seems mostly the same as Tasker and does NOT survive a Settings change)