# Prevent app to changing screen timeout

Tags: settings, screen-timeout

Some apps even disable screen timeout completely (although it's still says 30 seconds on the settings menu)

How to stop that ?

Not to forbid globally, as there are some apps that I DO control the timeout via tasker. But only for that app

Comment: Do you keep battery saver enabled? That causes the screen timeout to default to 30 seconds no matter how many times you change it.

Comment: I don't know yet if 3rd-party apps can change screen timeout without root access, but apps can indeed keep the screen awake. Not sure about the solution yet, but [Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) explains it further. Also, possibly related: [How to modify possible values screen timeout on rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/158467/44325), including an answer that mentions per-app setting.

Comment: Battery saver is off. The problem is apps telling the screen to stay ON, instead of obeying the system timeout.

Comment: That solution you don't know yet is everything that we need :cry: Guess the third party app is the patch, then. PerApp is the recommended one from your links. Needs root only to control the CPU, says there.